# .htaccess content printed on top of wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a weird error where the content of the wp-contents/.htaccess file is printed 4 times on any page I load on my WordPress website. It is the first thing printed, before `<!DOCTYPE html>`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch ".*\.(py|exe|phtml|php|PHP|Php|PHp|pHp|pHP|phP|PhP|php5|suspected)$">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "^(update.php|themes.php|dimensiones.php|duotones.php|spacings.php|wp-config-sample.php)$">
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

times 4...

The theme used is DIVI and plugins include
EWWW Image Optimizer
W3 Total Cache

Any ideas for how I get rid of this?

Comment: could you deactivate the plugins and test it again?

Comment: _Aside:_ Why do you have a front-controller pattern in the `/wp-contents/.htaccess` file?

Comment: @mrWhite I did not design the site in question and webpages/Wordpress are a bit outside my everyday work. I am just helping out a friend who contracted the page from a third party that probably no loger exits. That said I did not know about the front-controller pattern and it was interesting to read up on.

This .htaccess file with the same content is also repeated in every single subfolder under wp-contents. I find that very strange as well.

Comment: @Cray Thanks for the tip, I tried it but with no effect.

Comment: I just now also noted that the text only appear for logged in admin users. So not for customers on the website which is nice at least.

Comment: This is happening to me. Did you ever figure out what happened?